# Can't resize NSWindow due to frame always returning initial position

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

When I get my window's frame, it's always returning the initial position even after I have moved it by dragging it around the screen. I want to be able to programmatically resize the window, which I would do by getting the frame and altering the size, but because the frame's origin is not the correct one (after dragging), then the window snaps back to its initial position the moment I call `setFrame:`.

I tried unchecking `restorable` and `autolayout` in IB, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Didn't find any problem with the code. 
After I restart the system the issue disappeared.